# How to make ASP run sp_setapprole on connection?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm finishing off an ASP application, and in testing, my sa-enabled account was fine for everything.

However, this is not best practice. I did not want to individually assign permissions to windows groups and users for every database object a given group of users touches through the app. I know application roles are a thing for SQL Server, and that executing sp_setapprole to sign into the app role for permissions is the way I want to manage this, but I'm new to ASP and can't seem to find a way to get the pages to execute this procedure for every time it makes a connection. I feel like I'm missing an event somewhere. I have several pages which will need to behave this way, and one master page. If the code can be centralized, advise on how to do that would also be appreciated.

Comment: I think you could just create your own connection factory that returns an open connection after executing sp_setapprole. Importantly, note that sp_setapprole doesn't play nice with connection pooling so I suggest you avoid it.

Comment: I personally wouldn't use an app role here, but a database role (and just put the user in the database role). That is, `create role…` vs `create application role`

Comment: @BenThul The problem with that is when the *application* is allowed to add or change values in the `Users` table; but the (Windows) user should not. You don't want them firing up Excel and changing the underlying database.

Comment: It depends on who (from the database's perspective) is doing the work. Most allocation that I've worked with have one user that the application uses to connect to the database. In that case, giving that user permissions is sufficient. Alternatively, if you want to restrict the circumstances of certain operations, stored procedure with well for that.